# SharePoint 2019 on premise - User Profile Sync - show user properties in people search display

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-property

Our user profile sync is working well.

What I am not able to see are additional properties. Any good information on this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what additional properties are you referring to, but check out this article, see if it helps: https://www.rlvision.com/blog/how-to-create-searchable-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-online/

Comment: We were using a ps script which had an error while using cookies to check some data. We were able to alter the script and get it going.

Comment: Script which was adapted - our issue was around the function Dirsync function. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-User-Profile-928b39c0